# Existence of Galois Extension and a Normal Subgroup of the Galois Group containing Almost All Frobenius Elements

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Here is an interesting problem which arose out of a discussion:

Let $a, m$ be two coprime natural numbers and let $P$ denote the set of prime integers satisfying $p \equiv a \pmod{m}$. Does there exist a (finite) Galois extension $K / \mathbb{Q}$ and a normal subgroup $H$ of the Galois group $G:=Gal(K / \mathbb{Q})$ such that $|H|/|G| = 1/\phi(m)$ (where $\phi$ denotes the Euler Totient function) and for all sufficiently large integer primes $p$, we have $p \in P \iff \sigma_p \in H$?

Here $\sigma_p$ denotes the conjugacy class of the Frobenius substitution or Frobenius element (also known as the Frobenius Conjugacy Class), which is defined for all integer primes $p$ (not ramifying in $K$) and for all primes $\mathfrak{p}$ of $K$ lying over $p$, as the inverse image of the Frobenius automorphism under the canonical isomorphism $\pi_{\mathfrak{p}}: D_{\mathfrak{p}} \rightarrow Gal(k(\mathfrak{p})/\mathbb{F}_p)$ to the Galois Group of residue field extensions).

If we relax the condition of $H$ being a normal subgroup to that of $H$ simply being a subset that is closed under conjugation by elements of $G$, then considering the cyclotomic extension $K:=\mathbb{Q}_m = \mathbb{Q}(\zeta)$ (where $\zeta$ is of course a primitive $m$-th root of unity) does our job: it is an Abelian extension so that every subset of $G = Gal(K/\mathbb{Q})$ is closed under conjugation and it turns out that for **every** integer prime $p$, we have the equivalence 
$$p \in P \iff \sigma_p(\zeta) = \zeta^p = \zeta^a$$
(since the Frobenius element in a cyclotomic extension is simply the $p$-th power map on a generator). Therefore, letting $H$ be the singleton consisting of the $\mathbb{Q}$-automorphism of $K$ determined by $\sigma(\zeta) := \zeta^a$ does our job (since $|G|=\phi(m)$).

Of course $H$ (as defined above) despite being closed under conjugation is not a subgroup of $G$, and I can't seem to obtain any $G$ and $H$ which do the job either, so I am starting to suspect that the statement might be false. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

**Addendum:** The conditions imposed on $P$ might be strongly reminiscent of the Chebotarev Density Theorem, and in fact, if we relax the condition of $H$ being a subgroup of $G$ to simply that of being a subset closed under conjugation then we do get the conditions of Chebotarev. I would really appreciate some references or resources where such subsets $S$ of the primes (namely, those satisfying the condition that there exists $K, H$ as above such that $H$ is normal in $G$ and for every large enough prime $p$, $\sigma_p \in H \iff p \in S$) are studied? Perhaps they have some additional interesting properties (besides those arising out of Chebotarev)? Do there exist necessary and sufficient conditions characterizing them?

**Edit:** Ok, so just a clarification based on a comment. I am looking for a finite Galois extension $K/\mathbb{Q}$ such that there is **some** normal subgroup $H$ of $G$ which satisfies, for all sufficiently large integer primes $p$, the equivalence $p \in P \iff \sigma_p \in H$ (In other words, is there **some** finite Galois extension $K/\mathbb{Q}$ and **some** normal extension $E$ of $\mathbb{Q}$ contained in $K$ such that for all sufficiently large primes $p$, the Frobenius conjugacy class $\sigma_p$ fixes $E$ pointwise exactly for those $p \in P$?)

Comment: Your condition certainly implies that if $p$ splits completely in $K$, then $\sigma_p = e \in H$, and then $p \in P$. In particular it means that only primes $p \equiv a \pmod m$ may split completely in $K$. But only primes $p \equiv 1 \pmod m$ split completely in $\mathbf{Q}(\zeta_m)$. Hence, if $a \not\equiv 1 \mod m$, then no primes can split in $K(\zeta_m)$ which is a contradiction. Of course, if $a=1$, then you can take $K = \mathbf{Q}(\zeta_m)$ and $H$ the identity.

Comment: Also, the condition $\sigma_p \in H$ for some normal subgroup $H \subset G = \mathrm{Gal}(K/\mathbf{Q})$ is a convoluted way of saying that $\sigma_p$ is trivial in $G/H = \mathrm{Gal}(K^{H}/\mathbf{Q})$, so you may as well replace $K$ by $K^H$ and $H$ by the identity element.

Comment: Thanks for your response. It seems that are you fixing $K:=\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_m)$. Of course, it is clear that $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_m)$ is not going to work for $a \not\equiv 1 \pmod{m}$ (simply for order reasons: $|G| = \phi(m)$ so $H$ must be the trivial subgroup in order for $|H|/|G|$ to be $1/\phi(m)$. But, this means that the map $\zeta \mapsto \zeta^a$ must be the identity map which is equivalent to saying $a \equiv 1 \pmod{m}$.). How does it follow that there is no finite extension $K/\mathbb{Q}$ which does the job?

Comment: Did you even bother trying to read my comments? Please make some effort. Basically to repeat myself: Imagine $a=3$ and $m=4$. Do you understand: 1. Your conditions imply that any prime which totally splits in $K$ has to be $3 \pmod 4$? 2. The primes which split in $L = \mathbf{Q}(i)$ are $1 \pmod 4$? 3. The primes which totally split in the compositum $K.L$ of two extensions are the intersection of primes which split in $K$ and $L$? 4. Putting 1,2,3 together, there are no primes which can split completely in the compositum $K(i) = K.L$. 5. This is a contradiction by Chebotarev.

Comment: Ah okay, now I see! So this is your argument: If there exist such $K$, $H$ which satisfy my conditions, then by Chebotarev, the number of primes which totally split in $K$ must be infinite. But $\sigma_p=1$ for all such primes $p$ so in particular $\sigma_p \in H$ for all such $p$ which forces that for every prime splitting completely $p$ in $K$, we must have $p \equiv a \pmod{m}$. On the other hand, the primes which split completely in $K(\zeta_m)$ must split both in $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_m)$ and $K$ and hence must be congruent to both $1$ and $a$ modulo $m$, forcing $a \equiv 1 \pmod{m}$, right?